# Magento - Configurable products - No option to select... No Add to cart button

Tags: magento, attributes, configurable-product

I have a problem with my configurable products (Everything is OK for simple products - Add to cart button is available).
Indeed, in the frontend, these products are displayed but :

- The container where I should select values for option(s) does not appear
- ... CSQ? : The "Add to cart" button does not appear for these products.

I tried and checked:

- Status, Visibility, Qty, In stock for Simple products
- Attributes
- Attributes set
- to use a standard theme
- Simple products are associated to my configurable products
- If I create a new attribute, a new attribute set just for this attribute, 2 simple products and 1 configurable product, I have the same issue... I see my product, but the option remains unavailable.

What is the root cause?

Magento = 1.6.2.0

Comment: I suffer with the same issue. hope someone solves this fast.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me with this issue:

1) You have to do this for all configurable products
2) Go to the configurable product in "Manage Products" tab
3) Add a space after product name
4) Remove space that you just added
5) Hit the "Save" button

Basically you dont have to change anything just hit the save button. Its very weird but it works for me :P

Comment: I tried for one configurable product but it does not work for me. :(